# Firestore caching - does update/set modify cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If i perforrn a set/update on a document, will this automatically update the stored cache doc values? Or do i have to perform a server get() to ensure the values are updated in cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do a get-after-write to ensure your cache gets updated, the Firestore SDK takes care of that for you.

When you read data that is returned from the local cache that Firestore keeps, the data you get includes any changes that were made to that data from the local client.

Comment: That makes things a lot easier. I was thinking of changing my app to read the user doc from cache on app open (and if its not in cache read from the server). When they logout i was going to clear the firestore cache, but have read that this should only be done for testing.. Do you know why people would say that?

Comment: Why would you want to clear the cache? Is it not showing correct data? In general you should treat Firestore's cache as a transparent optimization, and not something you worry about.

Comment: It was mainly because of users logging out on one devices and logging in on another. I thought it could become completely un synched if they start updating their user doc on the second device and then switch back to the first devices. The force cache clear should fix that problem but if its not recommended im not sure how to fix this

Comment: Ah, in that case you can definitely clear the cache when the user signs out. Just don't think of it as a security mechanism, as any data on the device is stored unencrypted and should be considered accessible to everyone who has access to the device.

Comment: Sure thing :) One final question, is it only firestore docs that are stored in the cache? I just wanna double check i wont be clearing something in the background the firebase library has cached for performance or efficiency reasons

Comment: It's a cache. It's whole reason for existing is to improve performance. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

But nothing should fail by you clearing the cache right before/after the user signs out.